# Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton

Tags: android

Hey i'm just begined to learn android studio. and then i learned by watching some tutorials on youtube and  learn it. but when i want to test or start the project, i got some error message Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton etc.

```
04-04 20:00:18.896 3492-3492/com.example.exochese.project1 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.exochese.project1, PID: 3492
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.exochese.project1/com.example.exochese.project1.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2330)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #38: Error inflating class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:637)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365)
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378)
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2158)
    at com.example.exochese.project1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2158) 
    at com.example.exochese.project1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703) 
 Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x5
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:406)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.<init>(FButton.java:52)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:288) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:611) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:747) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:810) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:508) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:418) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:365) 
    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:378) 
    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:2158) 
    at com.example.exochese.project1.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:17) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6041) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1109) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2283) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2392) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:154) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5273) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:908) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:703)
```

==========================================================================

```
Main
```

```html
package com.example.exochese.project1;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Typeface;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    Button btnSignIn,btnSignUp;
    TextView txtSlogan;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        btnSignIn =(Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        btnSignUp =(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSignUp);
        txtSlogan = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtSlogan);
        Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/NABILA.TTF");
        txtSlogan.setTypeface(face);

        btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });

        btnSignUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

```
Gradle
```

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exochese.project1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //add library
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
    compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

```
Activity
```

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_1_my"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/mangan"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
            app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            app:shadowEnabled="true"
            app:shadowHeight="5dp"
            app:cornerRadius="4dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

and when I want to run the application. applications suddenly closed quickly without any warning. (I run it directly via android smartphone).
this is the codes of main and app

---

this is the colors format that i use

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#004d40</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#00251a</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#39796b</color>

    <color name="btnSignUp">#39796b</color>
    <color name="btnSignActive">#A9d440</color>
</resources>
```

there is something wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

Do the Following

Step 1:

In your build.gradle (Module: app) above 
Replace

**compile 'info.hoang8f:fbutton:1.0.5'** with

**compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'**

or better

**implementation 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'**

to avoid build warning.

Details about the libray can be foud [here](https://github.com/jd-alexander/android-flat-button)

Step 2:

In your Build.gradle (Project) file

add

**maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }**

in your repositories

Your repositories structure should look like this

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

}

In your activity.xml file

add

```
xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
```

after the relative layout declaration and then  use the   **fbutton** attribute instead of **app**

In summary, your  **buid.gradle (Module)** should look like this

```js
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.exochese.project1"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    //add library
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:12.0.0'
    compile 'com.github.jd-alexander:android-flat-button:v1.1'
    compile 'com.rengwuxian.materialedittext:library:2.1.4'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Your activity_main.xml should look like this

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:fbutton="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_1_my"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:src="@drawable/mangan"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp" />
    <TextView
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />


    </LinearLayout>
    
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
            android:text="Sign Up"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            fbutton:fButtonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
            fbutton:shadowHeight="5dp"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="4dp"
            />

        <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
            android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
            android:text="Sign In"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="8dp"
            fbutton:fButtonColor="@color/btnSignActive"
            fbutton:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
            fbutton:shadowEnabled="true"
            fbutton:shadowHeight="5dp"
            fbutton:cornerRadius="4dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

That error is telling you that the layout can't be inflated because there is an error on your FButton implementation:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to color: type=0x5
    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getColor(TypedArray.java:406)
    at info.hoang8f.widget.FButton.parseAttrs(FButton.java:116)
```

You don't show the FButton class, but it seems to be a problem in the initialization, while reading the attributes you added to the layout. One of these:

```
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
```

I'd say the problem is the value you put in the "btSignUp" field, which can't be converted to a color (the other color is from Android, so it is surely fine). 
¿Did you use the color format "#xxxxxx"? on a proper  tag? don't forget the #. Something like this (colors.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="btnSignUp">#3F51B5</color>
</resources>
```

Regards.